# Как присвоить при клике на кнопку содержимое input в пустой массив и потом массив вывести на страницу в div?

Tags: javascript

```js
let p = [];
let input = document.querySelector('.a-1');// input
let button = document.querySelector('.b-1');// button
let div = document.querySelector('.c-1'); //div

button.onclick = () => {
 let input2 = input.value;//присваиваю переменной a2 содержимое инпут
   p.innerHTML += input2;//пытаюсь содержимое input положить в пустой массив 
  console.log(p)
  div.innerHTML += p;
};
```

Comment: добавте разметку... ибо фиг пойми что такое а1 и тд...

Comment: отличная правка, а почему не назвать так переменние ?

Comment: `p.innerHTML += input2` - масив ето не дом елемент, почитайте про масивы :
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: `p.push( input2 );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так.

`p` - это массив. У него нет поля `innerHTML`. Для того чтоб добавить что-то к массиву, можно использовать метод `push()`.

Массив нельзя просто так взять и присвоить `innerHTML`, потому что `innerHTML` ждёт строку. Замените `div.innerHTML += input2;` на `div.innerHTML += p;` и посмотрите что получится.

```js
let p = [];
let input = document.querySelector('.a-1');// input
let button = document.querySelector('.b-1');// button
let div = document.querySelector('.c-1'); //div

button.onclick = () => {
  let input2 = input.value;//присваиваю переменной a2 содержимое инпут
  p.push(input2);//пытаюсь содержимое input положить в пустой массив 
  console.log(p)
  div.innerHTML += input2;
};
```

```html
<input type=text class=a-1>
<button class=b-1>Click</button>
<div class=c-1></div>
```